# Bypass capacitor in combination with ground plane

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, ground, ground-plane, bypass-capacitor

I read it is advisable that every IC has a bypass capacitor, as close as possible to VCC, going to GND.

However, I'm wondering, as I want to create a PCB with a GND layer as second layer, can I place the VCC pin of the bypass capacitor close to the VCC pin of the IC, and the GND pin of the capacitor directly to the GND plane, or should I create a separate 'connection' directly to the GND pin of the IC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a separate trace, but consider how the current will travel between the GND pin of the capacitor and the GND pin of the IC.

When the current doesn't have to travel as far, the impedance (most importantly the inductance) will be smaller, which is exactly what you want for a bypass capacitor.

The same goes for VCC: Arrange the PCB layout so that the current has the shortest possible path between capacitor VCC and IC VCC.

Also these traces should not be too thin. Therefore, using the ground plane to connect between capacitor GND and IC GND is usually a good thing.

Of course, if you break the ground plane by running some other trace between your two GND points, the current will have to make a detour around that other trace, which is not good. If it is necessary for some reason to break the ground plane in this way, you might want to run a regular trace between your GND points on a different layer as well.

It's all about keeping the impedance between the capacitor and the IC as low as you can.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. In my PCB I only need two or three via's and they are all away from the IC, so the bypass capacitor can use the shortest path possible (well except if I would put the bypass capacitor over the IC but that is what I do only for breadboarding).